# Error trying to start WEBrick in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

I'm struggling to get my WEBrick server started from within my rails project. This is an initial test to see if my setup is working. Everything is going well except that the server won't start now..

I'm getting the follow output in console when running

> rails s

[image]

I'd appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have MySQL server installed?

Comment: @MarekLipka I do yes, MySQL 5.6

Comment: @techvineet see attached screenshot (The huge picture above)

Comment: unfortunately i could not see it. Strange!

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
gem install mysql2 -- '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib" --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'
```

I found this snippet on [gamecreatures.com](http://www.gamecreatures.com/blog/2011/08/31/installing-ruby-on-rails-with-mysql-on-windows/). Be aware to paste in this command the correct mysql server path.

Hopefully this would fix your bug :) - Once installed it runs forever ^^

Comment: Thanks, but it still didn't work.. Your answer did point me in the general direction though and it seems that if you're running a 64bit version of mysql you're going to have troubles. So I'm attempting in installing 32bit of mysql and will let you know if that does the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to copy **libmysql.dll** file from lib folder of mysql installation and copy it into your lib folder of ruby installation.

Comment: Tried that and it didn't work either. I actually just gave up. Using SQL lite now

Comment: may be you should check your gemfile it should be mysql if your using mysql and mysql2 if you are using mysql2.